# Calling AS400 Programs through OleDb causes InvalidCastException

Tags: .net, oledb, ibm-midrange

I am trying to call an RPG program on our AS/400 machine using OleDb. As soon as there are more complex types such as dates and decimals I seem to be getting the following error:

> The data value could not be converted for reasons other than sign mismatch or data overflow. For example, the data was corrupted in the data store but the row was still retrievable.

Here is the code that produces the problem:

```
            //            'p_refno                     9a     ()
        //'p_projdat                   *date (output parm)
        //'p_amount                    13p, 2 (output parm)
        //'p_rtnsts                    1a (output parm)
        using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=IBMDA400;Data Source=MyAs400;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("{{call PGMLIB.MYPROGRAM(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}}", cn);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            OleDbParameter p_refno = new OleDbParameter("p_refno","ED4565654");
            OleDbParameter p_projdat = new OleDbParameter("p_projdat", new DateTime());
            p_projdat.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            p_projdat.Size = 8;
            OleDbParameter p_amount = new OleDbParameter("p_amount", new Decimal());
            p_amount.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            OleDbParameter p_rtnsts = new OleDbParameter("p_rtnsts", " ");
            p_rtnsts.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            p_rtnsts.Size = 1;
            p_amount.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Decimal;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p_refno);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p_mode);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p_source);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p_type);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p_projdat);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p_amount);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p_rtnsts);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine(p_projdat.Value.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(p_amount.Value.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(p_rtnsts.Value.ToString());

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I agree with FastAl about using strings if possible.  That is the easiest way.  If changing the AS/400 program is not an option, and *if* there is a way to get OLE DB to transfer values without trying to handle EBCDIC on its own, you may be able to bit-twiddle your way through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, use the IBM i Access ADO.NET drivers and place the program call in a stored procedure. They can convert the data from i to PC.

Comment: I do use it for data, but as far as I know that driver cannot call programs.

Comment: @Tjaart You are correct. It cannot directly call a program but that program can be called in a stored procedure and SQL on the i can call programs (Google Search it).

Comment: I have used stored procedures a long while ago to call programs. it seems to be the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Date formats (and binary numeric e.g., int/single, etc) differ between PC and mainframe platforms. You will need to convert them to text and then back again, unless the communications platform takes care of this for you - which obviously this one isn't doing.

There is probably a way to figure out how to do this, but if you are the only one using the mainframe piece and have the ability to change it, you will be hours ahead by forgetting about it and doing the converts yourself on both ends. (unless somebody who knows how reads this ;-)

If you can't change the as400 piece, well, don't accept this answer...

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the types. Some of these programs are being called by a whole lot of legacy programs. The one above is such an example. I saw something somewhere in the wild where you can call programs through sql server linked servers. Maybe that could be an option?

Comment: @Tjaart - this page implies there is a default parameter for your data provider that will convert date/times to char: http://www-912.ibm.com/s_dir/SLKBase.nsf/0/c52e46013ce1ded286256a3b006a38c5?OpenDocument:   Convert Date Time to Char (V5R1)

The convert date time to char property allows the programmer to choose how date, time, and timestamp values are represented. It this property is set to TRUE (the default), these data types are converted to string representations. However, if set to FALSE, these values are converted to PC data types representing date, time, and timestamps.

Comment: The system may be doing this for decimal types as well. Try requesting them as strings, see what comes back. Then take John Y's advice. You can stuff them in a byte array using encoding.utf8 and hack what the mainframe is sending (do take the time to write objects to conceal this mess from the business logic using it or you'll spend 10x the time debugging, trust me).